# basic java libgdx program runs in background after closing because of socket.io socket.connect

Tags: java, sockets, socket.io, background, libgdx

In a java libgdx project, the program continues running in the background on desktop even after it is closed.
This is happening due to the line `socket.connect();`
If that line of code is removed the program will close properly (i.e. not hang in the background).
Even closing the socket immediately after opening it does not stop this from happening. I cannot figure out why. Does anyone know why this is?

Additional info:

socket.io version:
`'io.socket:socket.io-client:2.0.1'`

java -version:

```
 java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
```

sample code from the simple program:

```
imports ...
import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

public class game extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private Socket socket;
    
    @Override // called when program starts
    public void create() {
        connectSocket();
        configSocEvs();
    }
    
    void connectSocket() {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket("http://localhost:8080");
            socket.connect(); // if this is commented out the program will not hang
            
                // socket is turned off right after it is created but the program still hangs
                socket.off();
                socket.disconnect();
                Gdx.app.log("   ", "socket closed");
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getStackTrace());
        }
    }
    
    // removing the code from this method does not stop the problem
    void configSocEvs() {
        socket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, new Emitter.Listener() {
            public void call(Object... args) {
                Gdx.app.log("EVENT_CONNECT", "client side callback method-EVENT_CONNECT");
            }
        });
    }

    /*Called when the program is closed*/
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // socket is disconnected again. this does not stop program hanging
        if (socket != null) {
            socket.off();
            socket.disconnect();
        }
        //System.exit(0); // if this is uncommented the program will NOT hang regardless of if the socket is closed.
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this problem:
You will have to override @hide from the screen interface like so:

```
@Override
public void hide() {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is correct solution for this problem. You should not call System.exit(0) from libgdx code. But how to correctly close process I don't know.